# Consume Application/pdf, Application/json rest response

Tags: spring-boot, rest, resttemplate, content-type

I'm consuming an API that returns a pdf(application/pdf) if everything goes fine. In case of exception, it returns a application/json response. How can I consume such response? How should my response class structure look like?

I'm thinking I can use

```
ResponseEntity<String> response
  = restTemplate.getForEntity(fooResourceUrl, String.class);
```

And then convert string to pdf or json depending on the content-type in the response header. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the success case, you can read the PDF response as a byte array as usual:

```
ResponseEntity<[]byte> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(fooResourceUrl, byte[].class);
```

For the failure case, you can catch [RestClientResponseException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestClientResponseException.html) and read the returned JSON as a string:

```
try {
   ResponseEntity<[]byte> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(fooResourceUrl, byte[].class);
} catch (RestClientResponseException e) {
   String json = e.getResponseBodyAsString();
   [...]
}
```